# Display caption overlay images vertically down the page

Tags: html, css, image

I have got 4 pictures that I had captions overlay on. I want the images to be one after another down the page.
e.g.

```
Image

Image

Image

Image
```

Problem is, right now, it's 2 pictures stuck side by side, a gap below them and another 2 pictures stuck side by side. E.g.

```
ImageImage

ImageImage
```

I think it might be my CSS but I can't figure out which part is causing this.

Here is my code:

CSS:

```
div.image {
float: left;
position: relative;
}

div.descript {
position: absolute;
bottom: 0px;
left: 0px;
width: 100%;
background:rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.6);
font-size:24px;
color: white;
}

p.content {
padding:10px;
margin:0;
}

.image .center {
display: inline-block;
vertical-align: middle;
height: 100%;
}
```

HTML:

```
<style>
img {
display:block;
margin-left: auto;
margin-right: auto;
}
</style>
</head>
<body>

<div class='image'>
<div class="center"></div>
<img src="images/batman.jpg" alt="HTML5 Icon"    style="width:576px;height:365px;">
<div class='descript'>
    <p class='content'> Batman </p>
</div>
```

There's 3 more blocks similar to the 'Batman' but with different images.

Thank you!

Comment: Head up to anybody stuck on this.
Figcaption is useful. CSS is very similar to the one Neophyte Polyhistor had posted.

Answer (score 0):

Replace your entire **CSS** with the followings:

```
div.image {
    display: block;
    }

div.descript {
    position: relative;
    bottom: 0px;
    left: 0px;
    width: 576px;
    background:rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.75);
    font-size:24px;
    color: white;
    margin-top: -50px;
    }

p.content {
    padding:10px;
    margin:0;
    }

.image .center {
    display: inline-block;
    vertical-align: middle;
    height: 100%;
    width: 100%;
    }
```

Comment: Hi! Thank you for answering so quickly! I actually tried that before and it's still the same wrong layout...

Comment: remove position:absolute from both your image and descript tags, check this link out, it looks perfectly fine on my screen https://jsfiddle.net/h0eu0edd/2/

Comment: Hi, I'd also used the display:inline-block on the JSFiddle and it turned out the layout I want, but someone when I run it on Chrome, it doesn't work.
Likewise, when I removed the positions, images stayed in the same spot but the overlay caption has turned grey
EDIT: And I need the positions for the captions to overlay on the bottom of the image

Comment: Have you got site online ? so I can take a look at iT ?

Comment: unfortunately no, I'm running it from the files :(

Comment: In what conditions your elements are aligned now ?

Comment: Still the same wrong layout.
ImageImage

ImageImage

Comment: This is weird, try changing it to "relative"!

Comment: It really is weird! Layout doesn't change...only the overlay does...thank you for helping though! You're too kind

Comment: take a picture of your layout and email it to neophyte.polyhistor@gmail.com, or update it in the question itself, so I can see !